# When is the subgroup product of two parabolic subgroups of a Coxeter Group, the Coxeter Group itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $W$ be a Coxeter Group generated by simple reflections $S$. If $I,J\subseteq S$ and $W_I = \langle s | s \in I \rangle$ when is it true that $W_IW_J = W$?

I am secretly hoping that the answer might be that this holds if and only if $I$ or $J$ = $S$. So a better follow-up question might be: for which Coxeter Groups is it true that $W_IW_J = W \iff \{I,J\} \cap \{S\} \ne \emptyset$.

I think I recall that this might be equivalent to a notion of flatness for some Coxeter Groups but I can't remember the source exactly. Any sources or comments that might be helpful would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks as though it is true if $I \cup J = S$ and all the elements of $I$ commute with all of those in $J$ or, more generally, if $I$ and $J$ have subsets $I'$ and $J'$ with $I' \cup J' = S$ and everything in $I'$ commuting with everything in $J'$.

Comment: I think this will be true in the connected case. At least in the finite case it seems like it can be shown by a counting argument (one for each type), but there might be a simpler argument (or there might be some subtlety I am missing). Starting with the easy type $A$ case at least seems to indicate that adding a simple root to each of the sets $I$ and $J$ will increase the size of the product, so you only need to consider maximal parabolics, which limits the number of cases to consider.